# postgres jsonb return any descendant of node

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I'm trying to parse the following JSON to return all product codes (PL,FG,KK) and their rrp value. I'd like to do this without hard coding the path to include the product code nodes (PL, FG, KK) - can anyone tell me how to get any descendant of a given node i.e xpath has the // concept to do this

```
{  "catalog": [
    {
      "product": {
        "PL": {
          "price": {
            "rrp": {
              "value": 232.75
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "desc": "d_pl"
    },
    {
      "product": {
        "FG": {
          "price": {
            "rrp": {
              "value": 132
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "desc": "d_fg"
    },
    {
      "product": {
        "KK": {
          "price": {
            "rrp": {
              "value": 36.15
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "desc": "d_kk"
    }
  ]
}
```

The output i'm trying to get is

```html
<table style="width:20%">
  <tr>
    <th>Product_Code</th>
    <th>Desc</th> 
    <th>RRP</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>PL</td>
    <td>d_pl</td> 
    <td>232.75</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td>FG</td>
    <td>d_fg</td> 
    <td>132.00</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td>KK</td>
    <td>d_kk</td> 
    <td>36.15</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The code i've tried so far is

```
WITH t(content) AS ( VALUES
  ('{"catalog": [    
  {      "product": {        "PL": {          "price": {            "rrp": {                  "value": 232.75            }          }        }      },      "desc": "d_pl"        },    
  {      "product": {        "FG": {          "price": {            "rrp": {                  "value": 132            }          }        }      },      "desc": "d_fg"    },    
  {      "product": {        "KK": {          "price": {            "rrp": {                  "value": 36.15            }          }        }      },      "desc": "d_kk"    }      ]}'::JSONB)
)
SELECT
  jsonb_object_keys(jsonb_array_elements(t.content -> 'catalog') ->     'product') AS product_code,
  jsonb_array_elements(t.content -> 'catalog') ->> 'desc' as Descr,
  jsonb_array_elements(t.content -> 'catalog') -> 'product' -> 'PL' ->     'price' -> 'rrp' -> 'value' as rrp  -- how do i define any node rather than hardcoded PL 
FROM t
;
```

But this obviously doesn't return all the records as its hard coded the PL.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem but this might not be the most elegant approach please

```
WITH t(myjson) AS ( VALUES
  ('{"catalog": [    
  {      "product": {        "PL": {          "price": {            "rrp": {                  "value": 232.75            }          }        }      },      "desc": "d_pl"        },    
  {      "product": {        "FG": {          "price": {            "rrp": {                  "value": 132            }          }        }      },      "desc": "d_fg"    },    
  {      "product": {        "KK": {          "price": {            "rrp": {                  "value": 36.15            }          }        }      },      "desc": "d_kk"    }      ]}'::JSONB)
)
SELECT
    product.key as product_code,
    products ->> 'desc' as descr,
    inner_price.value ->'rrp' ->> 'value' as rrp
FROM t,
     jsonb_array_elements(t.myjson -> 'catalog') products,
     jsonb_each(products -> 'product') product,
     jsonb_each(product.value) inner_price
WHERE
  inner_price.key = 'price'
;
```